# My Blog Needs some Upgrading !

Tags: seo, blog, widgets, blogger

I have been browsing all night for a way to improve my blog on blogger and actually nothing came up just that i could include some widgets that need java codes. Witch are the best widgets i could add without killing the SEO and where is a good place i could find ways to Tweak my blog and learn to sustain it better. It's my first blog and maybe it will not go viral but at least i want to try ! Thank you so very much !

Answer (score 2):

Before you start worrying about widgets, advertising, RSS, or any of the other peripheral components to your blog, you need to actually have good content. If you don't have good content, you can add all the widgets and "java codes" you want, and you'll still just have a useless blog that no one visits.

"Content is king" isn't just a cliche. It's an axiom of online success. You need to either provide a service that people want or publish content that people want. That's what makes your site useful. A blog is no different.

Once you have good, unique (original) content, you can think about monetizing, promoting, syndicating, etc. No one is going to come to your blog just for some sidebar widget you installed.

Adding widgets or JavaScript just for the sake of adding something isn't likely to be an improvement or upgrade. You should only add widget or code if you have a need. Otherwise, you're just doing it to be trendy or to create pointless novelty. Just look at all the old Myspace profiles with a million flash embeds and other useless widgets. They add no value to the page and instead just annoy users. Facebook apps are getting to be the same.

The only thing you should be adding to your blog for its own sake is content. And it will yield far better returns than a *"which TV show character are you?"* quiz or any other popular widget.

Answer (score 2):

i agree with @lese majeste you need to work on content, its the hardest part and the one i struggle with the most.

However to try and increase traffic or at least encourage my few readers to spread the word i have added twitter, linkedin and facebook buttons as this is where i promote my site the most and also where i generate the small amount of traffic i do get.

what you have to bear in mind is that just adding widgets is not going to increase traffic, i would look at your analytics on the site and see what phrases and content people are already finding you for then base articles around that while making sure the ways to share your content are obvious to all that visit.